# Javascript with Php MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm new in PHP MVC, I have a question about how javascript works with php mvc

If I have a page with a button, when user click the button
It will send to next page and update data in database

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $.load(){...   }    
        or $.post(){.....}//post data to another page
    });
});

//next page
if(isset($_POST[])){
  //update data
}
```

My question is

Should I send this data to controller than pass to model and output in view(if we need respond something)

```
Button --javascript--> controller -> model(update data) --send data back--> view
```

or

I can just send data to page and update without mvc

Comment: checkout this https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/7818/f06/lectures/19/arch.png

Comment: you can use javascript to send data to an API (view in MVC )and it will return back the result. you can't communicate with controllers or models using the javascript.

Comment: so you mean i use second approach, send data to page and update it without mvc?

Comment: PHP MVC is not going to affect the javascript. Javascript is completely independent from your php code. if you are using php you can respond with a json data to javascript and update your client view.

Comment: you can create your HTML output in your php Controller after you have received your required data from repository->Model , and by using `ob_start()` you can buffer your output and then use `ob_get_contents()` to get full output in a variable so you can echo it . in the javascript you can take it and put in in document using .innerHTML of your output container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sorry, i can't just comment your question yet*

Your first approach is correct. Is recommended that you update data in models. Meanwhile, all SQL statements or ORM handles should be on it.

In your case, you have two options to show the data in view: Return a JSON in your php handle it with javascript, and load your view directly after update data. It depends how all your project is builded.

I can write some exemples, but you will need to give some peace of code.

```
// In your controller
if(isset($_POST)){

    $obj = new MyObject();
    $obj->name = $_POST['name'];
    $obj->date = date("Y-m-d");
    $obj->validatePost();
    $obj->update();

    $result = $obj->getData();
    return $result;

}


// Your model
class MyObject {

    public $name;
    public $date;

    public function validatePost(){
        if($this->name == null){
            // print error
        }
    }

    public function update(){
        // database cheets
    }

    public function getData(){
        return $json;
    }

}
```

Comment: so should I put update method in same page controller? when I send data, create a new object and use method update?

Comment: thx a lot! I got it now, but sometime I felt MVC make app lots complex

Comment: See my edit. I assume that your controller is already handling the post

Comment: I can tell for sure. But generali, js, css and images keeps on a "public" folder.

Comment: OK thx a lots!, I just did some testing, I put in app folder but it wont work if my htaccss deny from all, so keeps on public folder

Comment: @BenjaminW What I do and have seen done is to have a resources folder inside your `app/` that uses something like webpack or gulp to output the compressed & bundled js/css to the public folder.